# Slow Video in Object Tracking Script using OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I wrote a short routine in openCV and C++ to track objects with a webcam. The webcam formulation was speedy with no lag, but before leaving work for the weekend, I recorded a typical sequence to use as a test template while I work until Monday. This and the corresponding change in code somehow make the video play back in really slow motion. Here is the code, opening "Test.avi", ~20 seconds long instead of running a constant stream off of the webcam:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

Mat drawBoundingBoxes (Mat canvasImage, vector<vector<Point>> contours);

int main(int argc, char** argv[])
{
    Mat frame;
    Mat back;
    Mat fGround;
    BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 bGround;
    bGround.nmixtures = 3;
    //bGround.nShadowDetection = 0;
    bGround.fTau = .5;

    VideoCapture cap;
    cap.open("Test.avi");
    if (!cap.isOpened())
    {
        cout << "Can't open video" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    vector<vector<Point>> contours;
    namedWindow("video", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    while (true)
    {
        static int count = 1;
        cap >> frame;
        if (frame.empty())
            break;

        bGround.operator()(frame, fGround);
        bGround.getBackgroundImage(back);
        erode(fGround, fGround, Mat(), Point(-1,-1), 2, BORDER_DEFAULT);
        dilate(fGround, fGround, Mat(), Point(-1,-1), 10, BORDER_DEFAULT);

        if (count > 50)
        {
            findContours(fGround, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
            drawContours(frame, contours, -1, Scalar(239,255,0), 2);
            drawBoundingBoxes(frame, contours);
        }

        imshow("video", frame);

        if(waitKey(30) >= 0) 
            break;
        count++;
    }
    return 0;
}

Mat drawBoundingBoxes (Mat canvasImage, vector<vector<Point>> contours)
{
    vector<Rect> boundRect(contours.size());

    for (int i=0; i<contours.size(); i++)
    {
        boundRect[i] = boundingRect(contours[i]);
        rectangle(canvasImage, boundRect[i], Scalar(153,0,76), 2, 8, 0);
    }
    return canvasImage;
}
```

Any ideas? Memory Leak somewhere? Thanks,

-Tony

Comment: "the corresponding change in code" -- which you've failed to identify in any way. It worked, you did *something* and now it plays too slow. Hmmm...

Comment: Sorry, I assumed anyone with OpenCV experience would know that the change is very, very minimal. The basic change to go back to the webcam feed version would be to remove these two lines: 

cap.open("Test.avi");
namedWindow("video", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

And replace:

VideoCapture cap;

with:

VideoCapture cap(0);

Sorry, and thanks for the reply!

Comment: Are the images in the new video very similar to the ones you were testing when using the webcam directly? Is it possible that either the background subtractor or the contour finding stage is taking much longer than usual because the images are more 'challenging'.

Comment: Test.avi was generated with the webcam and saved as a .wmv - I converted it online to an .avi. The video actually looks noticeably worse, but is possible that that made a difference?

Comment: I tried your code and I'm getting real time tracking using web camera. Did you by any chance change the video you were tracking? If it's a high quality video, that might have increased the processing time.

Comment: @user2067222 Although I am not familiar with this background subtraction technique, it may run a lot more slowly if there is noise or blurring in the image. One way to check would be to put timing functions around this part of the code. OpenCV supports this with a getTickCount() function.

Comment: Simple test: don't `blur()` and `erode()` the image and see if you notice a significant increase in performance. Another line of investigation is to print `cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS)` along with the width/height of the capture. If your input video has large frames than it makes sense that the performance is not that great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your recorded video has a higher framerate than that your PC can process real time. It's not a problem with a webcam as it just drops the frames. You could try to decrease the delay in the waitKey() procedure and see if that helps.